# Is it possible to make add section number to to constants using the constants package

Tags: math-mode, formatting, numbering

I am using the [constants](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/constants/constants.pdf) package to auto number my constants. However I want the constants indices to reflect my section number. For instance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{constants}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Let $\Cl{important}$ to be a positive constant...

\end{document}
```

If I am in section 1, then I want 'important' to look like $C_{1.1}$. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete and compilable document (commonly called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) that shows the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, and I have updated a compliable document.

Comment: With `$\Cl{important}$` numbered within section, what output do you expect from `$\Cr{important}$`?